# prevent login Form from submission (AJAX) when credentials dont match (return false not working)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, form-submit

This is my form:

```
 <form name="loginform" method="POST" action="login" onsubmit="return validateLogin()">            
<div>  User Name  :<input class="input" name="username" type="text" /> </div> 
<div> Password  :<input class="input" name="password" type="password" /> </div>        
<div> id="yaha" style="color:red;font:bold 16px garamond"</div>                         
<input style="font-weight:bold;" type="submit" value="Login" />
```

javascript code is as shown:

```
function validateLogin()
{
var x1=document.forms["loginform"];
if(//validations)
      {
       return false;
      }
 else
{    goajax(x1.username.value,x1.password.value);}        
 }//validate login ends...

var requ = null;

function goajax( u,  p)
{
requ=new XMLHttpRequest();
//code for posting ajax data
requ.onreadystatechange=display;

} 
function display()
{
if(requ.readyState == 4)
{
    if(requ.status == 200)
    {
    var message = requ.responseText;
    alert("message==="+message);
    var x;
    if(message.trim() == "ok")
        {
        var x1=document.forms["loginform"];
        return true;
        }
        else if(message.trim() == "no")
        {
        document.getElementById('yaha').innerHTML="Invalid Username or Password!!!";
        x1.password.value="";
        return false;
        }
        else if(message.trim() == "nv")
        {
        document.getElementById('yaha').innerHTML="Account not Activated";
        return false;
        }
    }     
}
```

}

**My question is**: I am getting the responses from the server as desired but in case of undesired responses, the form is getting submitted even after "return false;" (see function display())

**Please scroll down to function display() i don't want the form to be submitted when message is "no" or "nv". basically "return false" is not working**

Comment: Is it even valid JS with the comment in three middle of an expression like that? Or are you trying to indicate there's other code there?

Comment: @DaveNewton i did not to post unwanted part of the code!!

Comment: is your validation working properly?

Comment: yes it simply checked if the fields are left empty...

Comment: Do it this way. First you get your data by ajax. After getting it put validation on the received textfields. so there should be functions. First getting ajax, second giving validation and making submission true or false

Comment: please put a reduced example of your code problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link because I couldn't reproduce your problem there...

Comment: @polin but why should i get the data if the user is clicking on login without entering anything..these are basic validations

Comment: @TheZuck because it is an AJAX query it has to go to the server connect to db and then the results appear

Comment: @MayankSharma There you go. If the text fields are empty then call a validation, not through ajax. It will be simple one. If user gives anything then connect to database and fetch required data.compare it and show it is valid or not. Not tell us where you are facing problem

Comment: @polin that is exactly what i am doing..but in the display() function when i am getting to know that the user is invalid i return false if the response is OK i return true.but the form is getting submitted in any case..basically "return false;" is not working

Comment: Your code seems ok. now check what are go getting in return in console or by giving an alert. also your third div is  not closed.make it right

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to [cancel the default event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) (in this case the submit)

Like this:

```
function validateLogin(e)
{
var x1=document.forms["loginform"];
if(//validations)
      {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [jQuery preventDefault();](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/&ei=BEbQUI_9J4WV0QWw94DwCw&usg=AFQjCNHWzAujRZvCkrcZnoFZi9g6cX38ZA&sig2=MMMKw5FLbmipMqcAkHbLLA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k)

Try posting with jQuery (If you are using it in the website)

Comment: It implements the same function.

Comment: That's my point. No need to include a 32kB library for something you can do with 10 bytes of [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: You have a point, anyways I think I do not deserve downvote cuz as almost every website is running jQuery and if he is using it he could du it with it. Anyways I will take a note

Comment: I removed my -1. The disclaimer "(If you are using it in the website)" works for me. :)

Comment: Tnx, I will keep that in mind when posting next time. =) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a lot of this in my current project using jQuery this way:

$('#form').submit(function () {

call_function_to_validate_and_submit();
return false;

});

Whenever I have a javascript error (syntax or other) the form gets submitted (like in a normal html form with no ajax) even if validation fails. My point is that you might have a syntax error somewhere in there.